# log4j2 upgrade with log4j1 adapter email trigger not working

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2

I upgraded my log4j2 from log4j1 with the help of `log4j-1.2-api` adapter as one of the api which I consume still using log4j1 so had to use the log4j1 adapter. After the upgrade i observed log4j2 is not triggering email. Except the dependency upgrade i have not updated the log4j properties file  , here is the log4j.properites to send email

```
#Email logger
log4j.logger.EMAIL=INFO, SMTP
log4j.additivity.EMAIL=false
log4j.appender.SMTP.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
log4j.appender.SMTP=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.SMTP.From=noreply@test.com
log4j.appender.SMTP.SMTPHost=mail-gw.test.net
log4j.appender.SMTP.Subject=issue reported
log4j.appender.SMTP.To=my@email.com
```

is there anything new added to support email send in log4j2?
version of log4j2 is 2.17.x